# Swift 2.x -> Swift 3.0 conversion issue with String.fromCString

Tags: swift, string

I have the following Swift 2.x syntax:

```
if let columnType = String.fromCString(sqlite3_column_decltype(pStmt, i))?.uppercased() {
```

I'm trying to convert my code to swift 3.0. However I can't get this statement to work. Currently I have the following but its giving me: *"Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'String'"*

```
if let columnType = String(cString: sqlite3_column_decltype(pStmt, i))?.uppercased() {
```

Comment: Remove the question mark.

Comment: @CleverError `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`String(cString:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641523-init) in Swift 3 does not return an optional:

```
let columnType = String(cString: sqlite3_column_decltype(pStmt, i)).uppercased()
```

Invalid UTF-8 bytes are replaced by the Unicode replacement character
U+FFFD.

Or use [`String(validatingUTF8:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1641706-init) which returns an optional (`nil`
if the input is not a valid UTF-8 sequence):

```
if let columnType = String(validatingUTF8: sqlite3_column_decltype(pStmt, i))?.uppercased() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You are really fast! For anyone looking further information, please take a look at the CString extension -> https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/CString.swift